# Can the smash ultimate gamecube controller be used on a gamecube?

Tags: nintendo-gamecube

Just wondering because I have a gamecube with one controller, and I wanted to use the smash ultimate edition controller on my gamecube.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** the [Wired Smash Ultimate Controller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DJX3Y47) is just a regular GameCube controller intended to be used with a GameCube controller adapter on Switch or Wii U. There isn't anything different about it aside from the design and the fact that it is being currently manufactured. The wireless controller will not work, however, as that one is strictly a Switch controller.

Comment: @zxch. If this answer helped, consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).